# What is the difference between "lernanto" and "studanto"?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Both "lernato" and "studanto" means "student", right? When should I use which one?

Answer (score 6):

A *lernanto* is at primary or high school, while at universities you can find a *stud**e**nto*. And a *stud**a**nto* is any person studying something, so a pupil, a student, a normal working person who is just learning something new, or a scientist working on a specific problem.
Sometimes people use *studanto* en the more specific sense of *studento*, what is nevertheless not recommendable.

Examples:
*Mia 15-jara filo estas lernanto en gimnazio, kaj mia 20-jara filino estas jam studento de lingvistiko. Ambaŭ de kelkaj semajnoj estas fervoraj studantoj de Esperanto.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My instinctive idea would be that "lernanto"  is used for anyone who happens to be "learning something new", while "studanto" means someone who is studying (for example at a university). Do you have any sources linked to your answers I can use to find out more?

Comment: Compare the definitions in "Plena Ilustrita Vortaro", the best available monolingual dictionary of Esperanto:
http://vortaro.net/#lernanto
http://vortaro.net/#studento
http://vortaro.net/#studi
The definiton of _studanto_, however, to me seems even to broad. Like _lernejo_, which is not any place you learn at, but specifically "school", IMHO also _lernanto_ is mostly confined to school. I would not call my students at university "lernantoj".
However, in a clear context, where you don't mean a kind of profession, but an acting person, you can say _lernanto_ in the sense "learning one".